# Accessing derived class members with a base class pointer

Tags: c++

I am making a simple console game in C++

I would like to know if I can access members from the 'entPlayer' class while using a pointer that is pointing to the base class ( 'Entity' ):

```
class Entity {
public:
    void setId(int id) { Id = id; }
    int getId() { return Id; }
protected:
    int Id;
};

class entPlayer : public Entity {
    string Name;
public:
    void setName(string name) { Name = name; }
    string getName() { return Name; }
};

Entity *createEntity(string Type) {
    Entity *Ent = NULL;
    if (Type == "player") {
        Ent = new entPlayer;
    }
    return Ent;
}

void main() {
    Entity *ply = createEntity("player");
    ply->setName("Test");
    ply->setId(1);

    cout << ply->getName() << endl;
    cout << ply->getId() << endl;

    delete ply;
}
```

How would I be able to call ply->setName etc?

OR

If it's not possible that way, what would be a better way?

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit your code formatting. The blank lines made your code really tall! Another little comment about your code: stick with a consistent naming convention e.g. AllClassNamesLikeThis, and parameter_names_like_this. Another nit: you'll kick yourself in the butt later with abbreviations like "ent". I honestly cannot tell what an entPlayer is supposed to be. I think what you mean is just "Player", or if you're feeling verbose "PlayerEntity".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible by using a cast.  If you know for a fact that the base class pointer points to an object of the derived class, you can use `static_cast`:

```
Entity* e = /* a pointer to an entPlayer object */;
entPlayer* p = static_cast<entPlayer*>(e);
p->setName("Test");
```

If you don't know for sure, then you need to use `dynamic_cast` and test the result to see that it is not null.  Note that you can only use `dynamic_cast` if the base class has at least one virtual function.  An example:

```
Entity* e = /* a pointer to some entity */;
entPlayer* p = dynamic_cast<entPlayer*>(e);
if (p)
{
    p->setName("Test");
}
```

That said, it would be far better to encapsulate your class's functionality using polymorphism (i.e. virtual functions).

Speaking of virtual functions, your class hierarchy as implement has undefined behavior:  you can only delete an object of a derived type through a pointer to one of its base classes if the base class as a virtual destructor.  So, you need to add a virtual destructor to the base class.

Comment: I had a related question, which this answer answers :D What I wanted to know was "How can I tell whether my base pointer actually points to a derived object?". The answer that I'm gleaning is use dynamic_cast (only works if the base class has a virtual function). Then, see if the result is NULL. #victorybaby

Comment: This also (partially) answers another question that I've had for a while about C++: What is the difference between the various types of casts? There sure seems to be a good number of them!

Answer (score 1):

I would consider doing something like this:

```
public:
void setId(int id) 
{

    Id = id;

}

void virtual setName( string name ) = 0; // Virtual Function 
string virtual getName() = 0; // Virtual Function

int getId() { return Id; }

protected:
    int Id;

};

class entPlayer : public Entity {

    string Name;

public:
    entPlayer() {

        Name = "";
        Id = 0;

    }

    void entPlayer::setName(string name) {  // Must define function

        Name = name;
}

string entPlayer::getName() { return Name; } // again must define function here

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a dynamic cast:

```
entPlayer * pPlayer = dynamic_cast<entPlayer *>(pointer_to_base);
```

This will (if successful) result in a derived pointer.

Otherwise `NULL` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

C++ makes what you are trying to do really awkward, because this is probably not what you should be doing, and it is trying to lead you to good object-oriented design. In fact, by default, [compilers often disable run-time type information](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) (RTTI), which is needed to make dynamic_cast work.

Without knowing your broader context, it's hard to say what you should do instead. What I can say is that if you wanted a more specific pointer, <strike>you should have put a ring on it</strike> you almost certainly shouldn't use a function that returns an `Entity*`, and there is probably a better approach.