# Getting derived members from base class pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I was told that a base class pointer can point to any derived types of that base class. However, I need to access this derived class even though the argument is calling a pointer to  base class.

Here `Meeting` is the derived type, `ListItem` is the base type, `CompareByInsertKey` is a mandatory purely virtual function in ListItem overriden by `Meeting::CompareByInsertKey`, and `Meeting` has a structure called `thisdate` with a member `year`. In this instance, item_in_list would be a Meeting type but apparently the pointer still works even though it's a derived type.

```
int Meeting::CompareByInsertKey(ListItem* item_in_list)
{
    int compare = (*item_in_list).thisdate.year;
    return compare;

}
```

How do I allow this method to take  in a derived or base class argument and allow it to use derived class members?

In other words, I need to access a derived type's private members in a method of that derived type. The problem is that the `CompareByInsertKey` function must take a base class pointer in order to override the purely `virtual ListItem::CompareByInsertKey`

Thanks,
if you need any more information, please let me know

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing derived class members with a base class pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785309/accessing-derived-class-members-with-a-base-class-pointer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `dynamic_cast`, like this:

```
int Meeting::CompareByInsertKey(ListItem* item_in_list)
{
    Meeting *meeting = dynamic_cast<Meeting*>(item_in_list);
    // dynamic_cast returns a null pointer if the passed pointer is not
    // of the requested type
    if(meeting == 0) {
       ...
    } 
    int compare = meeting->thisdate.year;
    return compare;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up today, the only way I can see is to do a type check and cast using `dynamic_cast`. This ensures that mismatched types are not passed in.

```
int Meeting::CompareByInsertKey(ListItem* item_in_list)
{
    Meeting* meeting = dynamic_cast<Meeting*>(item_in_list);
    if(NULL != meeting)
    {
        int compare = meeting->thisdate.year;
        return compare;
    )
    else // return error value
}
```